# How can i replace an Array inside of an object with new array with multiple objects inside?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, react-redux

I have initial values in react redux state which is basically fetched from an API. which is in the data

```
let data = {    
    item: [],
    name: "random",
    description: "hello",
    status: "true",
    asset: [],
    version: "0.043",
    }
```

now I want to replace the item array [] from the dat with the item array below

```
let item = [
{
    item: 
{
    name: "random",
    description: "General Description",
    status: "true",
    asset: [],
    version: "0.043",
   },
   quantity: "344"
   },
   {
   item: {
   name: "random",
   description: "General Description",
   status: "true",
   asset: [],
   version: "0.043"
   },
   quantity: "434"
   }
   ]
```

what I want to achieve is to update the react redux state and then post it to the Api

```
data = {
    item: [
    {
     item: {
        name: "random",
        descr: "General Descr",
        status: "true",
        asset: [],
        version: "0.043",
     },
      quantity: "344"
      },
      {
     item: {
        name: "random",
        descr: "General Descr",
        status: "true",
        asset: [],
        version: "0.043",
     },
      quantity: "344"
      }                     
     ],
    name: "random",
    description: "hello",
    status: "true",
    asset: [],
    version: "0.043",
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the spread operator for this to make a copy of the `data` and `item`. Which you can then use in your *redux* part of the code

```js
data = { ...data, item: [...data.item, ...item] };
```

Comment: If this was the correct answer, you can accept it as the correct answer to help others who might have the same issue in the future @MuhammadMisbahUlHaq

Comment: Is there any other way to accept the answer. I upvoted it but I don't have much reputation that's why its not accepting.